# How to get the data used in AudioPlot

Tags: plotting, sound

How can I get the data used to plot when using `AudioPlot` that produces a graph such as:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`AudioData`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/AudioData.html) to get the data from an `Audio` object.

Comment: awh thanks, are both `AudioData` and `AudioPlot` set to the same default settings so without specifying parameters they will give the same (data)?

Comment: I'm using `ListLinePlot` and it just seems to stall for ever, should I use a different plotting function?